# How to change default words in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, locale

I am using Rails 5.2.2 . I use the method:

```
distance_of_time_in_words(@customer.accounts.last.updated_at,Time.now)
```

And this gives me the output like "`9 days`". I want to change that `days` to my language.What is the correct way to change it ?

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the [I18n Gem](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n)

and in `config/environment/development.rb`

add this line

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :fr #:fr is for french language  for example
```

Comment: Thanks. It says "undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object (NameError)"

Comment: As alternative to have to hassle that everything else gets translated.
`distance_of_time_in_words(@customer.accounts.last.updated_at, Time.now, {locale: :fr})` for just translating this string. This still required I18n gem for having all the common translations.

Comment: @DennyMueller it worked thanks. But why i can't add it to environment.rb ?

Comment: did you add this line in `config/environment/development.rb`?

Comment: config/environment/ is a folder with your differents environments (development.rb , production.rb, test.rb)

Comment: @Zogimu What @NEL said. It nees to be in the `configure` block of `development.rb`

Comment: happy to help :)